# Create a program in Java wherein if a year is a leap year will return true otherwise false

Tags: java

This is my code

```
public class Leapyear{
  public static void main(String []args){
    for(int year =2000; year <=2020; year++){
      if((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)))
        System.out.println("Year " + year + " is a leap year");
      else
        System.out.println("Year " + year + " is not a leap year");
}
```

but the question is: I don't know that how to return true if it's a leap year and false if it's not a leap year.

Comment: Erm ... the `return` statement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a method that will judge whether a year is leap year or not. Like this.

```
public class Leapyear{
    public static void main(String []args){
        for(int year =2000; year <=2020; year++){
            if(isLeapYear(year)) {
              System.out.println("Year " + year + " is a leap year");
            else
              System.out.println("Year " + year + " is not a leap year"); 
        }
     }

    public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
        return (year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)) /* It will return boolean value (true or false) */
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

> Create a program in java wherein if a year is a leap year will return true otherwise false

A program cannot return `true`.  A program does not return anything in the Java sense.  It can set a return code, but that is a number, not `true` or `false`.

(The way to set a return code is to use `System.exit(int)` ... where the parameter is the return code.  The code is typically truncated to a value between -128 and +127 ... though that is OS dependent.)

A method can return `true`, but a `void` method cannot return anything.

If you want to declare a method that can return `true` or `false`, then you need to declare the return type to be `boolean`; e.g.

```
    public boolean isLeapYear(int year) { /* you fill in the rest */ }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this:

```
public boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    return ((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)));
}
```

Pass in the year you wish to check, and the function will return you true/false based on whether that is a leap year.

**Note:** I am assuming the program just needs to contain a method that is able to return true/false based on the condition mentioned in the question, and not a program that returns true/false (which cannot be done).

Answer (score 0):

To be able to return `true` or `false` you need a method that's declared to return a `boolean`:

```
public static boolean isLeapYear(int year) {
    if ((year % 400 == 0) || ((year % 4 == 0) && (year % 100 != 0)))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

And then call that method inside `main`:

```
for (int year = 2000; year <= 2020; year++) {
    if (isLeapYear(year))
        System.out.println("Year " + year + " is a leap year");
    else
        System.out.println("Year " + year + " is not a leap year");
```